# Solr - search suggestions

Tags: solr

Some of my product names are:

```
Bella cycling gloves for women white and graphite size L
Daisy cycling gloves for children white and blue size XS
Bars cycling gloves for men red size XL
```

Using Solr to search them is not a problem, but i would also like to make suggestions for searching.

So when someone is writing in search input:

```
cycling gloves
```

I would like Solr to give **suggestions** like:

```
cycling gloves for children
cycling gloves for men
cycling gloves for women
bella cycling gloves
daisy cycling gloves 
bars cycling gloves
```

I tried various examples, but none worked.

If u can please provide me example with **schema** and **solrconfig**.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a secondary field with a shingle filter attached to generate tokens of a certain length (2/3/4 words combined).

Comment: Will it also get the words before the keyphrase? Like "bars cycling gloves"...

Comment: That depends on how you define the sequence, which suggester you're using and the cut-off point for your suggester. However, to get perfect results you'll have to do a more manual approach with categories, brand names, etc.

Comment: The problems is that none of example suggesters i used gave me even close results. Can u maybe give me some example config files to test your approach?